# PHP: How do I change a color in an 8 bit PNG (png has transparency) using GD Library

Tags: php, gd

I have an 8 bit PNG (original is here: https://i.ibb.co/s3024Y8/1000x1500-autumn-leaves.png) and I want to change the colour of the leaves.

I have a list of the hex colours that need to be changed and a list of the colours they need to be changed to - all to be done dynamically. I'm working towards a solution that has to work off those lists - but that can wait. For this question, being able to change the colour of just one leaf will do.

After changing the colour of the leaf I need the image to retain its transparent areas (so I can lay it on top of another image - that part I can do).

I am quite new to the GD library and am getting confused. I understand that an 8-bit PNG (as created in Photoshop) has full alpha - and that needs to be preserved.

That leads me to the start of my code:

```
$im = ImageCreateFromPNG('https://i.ibb.co/s3024Y8/1000x1500-autumn-leaves.png');
ImageAlphaBlending($im, false);
imagesavealpha($im, true);
```

Everything I've tried after that fails miserably. By that, I mean that the colour doesn't change. No error message, just no change in colour. It seems that the following has no effect when using that image:

```
$myColourToChange = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 100, 24, 11, 0); // colour of dark brown leaf
imagecolorset($im, $myColourToChange, 255, 0, 0, 0); // try changing it to red, fully opaque
```

I've even tried (which gives 6559755)

```
$myColourToChange = imagecolorresolvealpha($im, 100, 24, 11, 0);
```

I *think* things are failing (ie the colour doesn't change) because the image I'm using isn't a paletted image in the way that GD needs it to be, in order for me to use `imagecolorset`

I've tried converting it to one using `imagetruecolortopalette` but that gives unpredictable results on the image, with all sorts of artifacts not visibly present in the original image - and the colour values change slightly.

Note that the following are representations if you want to experiment, use the image link above.

Original image before `imagetruecolortopalette` - dark brown leaf colour: #64180B

[image: Before - dark brown leaf colour: #64180B]

After `imagetruecolortopalette` - dark brown leaf colour: #631A0C

[image: After - dark brown leaf colour: #631A0C]

So how do I specify the colour that needs to be changed and then change it to the given colour? If it means I must use `imagetruecolortopalette` how do I deal with the artifacts and the colour change I get when using it?

(I won't know in advance the location of colours that need changing, so `imagecolorat` won't help)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Edit your question to include what “failing miserably” means. If you get an error, include it. If the image is wrong, include it!

Comment: I've done as you suggested, @miken32 - thanks :)

Comment: I've resolved the artifacts issue in the original png. Merging the layers in Photshop (CS3), selecting the 'empty' background and hitting delete was the key to success.